# Add 'continue shopping' on WooCommerce checkout page before order review

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add 'continue shopping' / 'add product' link before order review on checkout page. But I want it to be inline with "Your order" text.

See this screenshot: https://ibb.co/47f6vd7

I tried this code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_review','woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_add_product');
function woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_add_product(){
    
    $continue_shopping_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    $add_product_label = 'add product';

    if(!empty($continue_shopping_url)){
        echo "$add_product_label";
    }
}
```

But it show on the line below "Your order" text. So it looks ugly.

How do i make it inline with "Your order" text using additional css?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using the wrong hook.

While `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` will cause the text to be added insde the `#order_review` div, the `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` hook will cause it to be placed before the `#order_review` div.

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review(){
    $continue_shopping_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' );
    $add_product_label = 'add product';

    if ( ! empty ( $continue_shopping_url ) ) {
        echo '<div class="my-label">' . $add_product_label . '</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```

Which CSS you will have to apply for this is completely theme dependent,
but using `display: inline-block;` can certainly come in handy

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) setup. You can then add the 'Continue shopping' link via the `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` action hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_add_continue_shopping_link' );
function woocommerce_checkout_add_continue_shopping_link() {
    printf( '<a href="%s" class="checkout-continue-shopping">Continue shopping</a>', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
}
```

Add the above code snippet to the functions.php of your child theme. Then take care of the CSS styling in the style.css of your child theme.

For instance like this:

```
body.woocommerce-checkout h3#order_review_heading {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

body.woocommerce-checkout a.checkout-continue-shopping {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    float: left;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    background: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.25em;
}
```

Which will give you the following result:

[image]

You will probably also have to add some [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to make this look good on mobile and tablet.